# What is the best way to retrieve UserId in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to create a basic card game like Hearthstone but much much simpler :D

Basically, every user has an Inventory that contains a list of cards. I created a MyInventoryController where you should be able to retrieve your own inventory, add new Card to it and delete if you want to.

So I guess I need to get the User's id from somewhere to be sure that the new card is placed in the correct user's inventory.

As I was searching the web I couldn't find anything useful, mostly outdated stuff.

So here comes the question, how do you do it? You make a new UserRepo or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the User Id with `User.Identity.GetUserId()` since he's is logged in and makes the call to the controller.